# Google Sheet Save APIKEY for user

Tags: google-sheets

Im writing a Google Sheet Addon.
The Addon is calling my backend API with a user uniqe APIKEY (a string).

The problem is to save the APIKEY for only one user.
I need to APIKEY to be saved for one user, so next time the user open the sheet or create a new sheet, then the APIKEY is loaded. I dont want the user to re-enter the APIKEY.

I tried to use getDocumentCache() or getUserCache() but when I share the sheet with another User X then User X can call API with my APIKEY.
I need the APIKEY to be Uniqe for one user.
Its not ok to share the APIKEY with many users.

I will publish the addon in Google Store when its finished.

Is there a better way to store my APIKEY?

Thanks,
Henrik

Comment: Hi, I don't think hardcoding the API Key is a good idea for security reasons. What does you addon do?

Comment: Hi, No hardcoding :)   I have a meny textinput where the user enter his uniqe APIKEY.  I save this in PropertiesService.getUserProperties().  This works ok for one user with one sheet.   The problem is when the user Share the Sheet with other users. Then the APIKEY still works for the shared users. I want the APIKEY to only work for one user.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Are the rest of users in your same domain? Or is it a public addon?

Comment: Great. Its a public Addon. It will be deployed in Google Store when ready.